# Which design mode to select and how to do in this situation?

Tags: java, android, designmode

I'd like developer an Android app in JAVA.

But not quite familiar with design mode.

This this situation, I want to define a class and unique instance Group. And a serious functions, such as setName, createGroup

Well, should I create a GroupManager class and move the setName, createGroup functions to this class, and manager the unique Group instance via GroupManager?

Any answer will be appreciated.

Comment: It depends. But why would you do that? Setters and some creator are perfectly suitable to the Group class itself

Comment: Cause I want to make the class Group a model. createGroup needs a lot  of work to do that make Group not so clean.

Comment: So... why don't you provide us some code? What have you tried, what does your class look like. It would be much easier to help than now.